# RXTX causes jvm crash when printer is switched off

Tags: java, jvm, rxtx

I have a trouble with the rtxt COM library. I connected a USB printer to the Virtual COM driver. Everything works properly however if I switch off the printer the jvm crash! The error out of the box are located on rxtxSerial.dll... but i have not other log (where should I find it?)

This is a big problem because the port listener runs on a tomcat server ... and it is not good to crash the server when a printer is switched off :-)

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried to setup the enviroment in a 32bit system and now rxtx doesn't crash the jvm... just enter in a deadlock. I read about this deadlock of rxtx when a device is unplugged or switched off: http://mailman.qbang.org/2011-January/8573059.html
I did not find a solution yet, I will start to try every workaround!

Comment: When the JVM crashes in native code, it usually writes a log file in its working directory. The filename has the format "hs_err_pidXXXX.log". Can you locate this file in your server?

Comment: I looked under tomcat or eclipse folder but i did not find that file. I also tried to specify -XX:ErrorFile=d:\ but nothing changed.

Comment: I did not found any valid workaround for x64... also with the newer 2.2 version the jvm crashes